# Code Igniter Session vairable is being destroyed prematurely

Tags: codeigniter, session

We have developed an web application using CodeIgniter. Our All functionality working well. Unfortunately when we are going to use another page/feature/module of our application then the application is going to logout automatically and telling me to signin again. I am not understanding the issue. Can anyone help me please?

Although I have used session library correctly .

Comment: Have you checked sess_expiration value in config ?

Comment: Check if by mistake your logout function get call. If you checking login with preload helper or any other class,than check that. If you using session_id for login check than check increase `sess_time_to_update` in config file.

Comment: you are using CI `database sessions` or `php native session` ?

Comment: are you using database sessions? do you have any ajax involved?